# Multiple routing in flask- Python

Tags: python, flask

I am a beginner in flask - Python. I am facing an issue with multiple routing. I had gone through google searches. But didn't get the full idea of how to implement it. 
I have developed an flask application where i need to reuse the same view function for different urls.

```
@app.route('/test/contr',methods=["POST", "GET"],contr=None)
@app.route('/test/primary', methods=["POST", "GET"])
def test(contr):                                          
    if request.method == "POST":
        if contr is None:
            print "inter"
        else:
            main_title = "POST PHASE"
...
```

I want to call test function for 2 routing..& have different in few functionalities, except that all other are same. So i though of reusing. But not getting how to differentiate routing inside the test function using some parameters passing from function which redirects the call to this test function.

I couldn't find a good tutorial which defines basics of multiple routing from scratch

Comment: Why not just use two route functions for your two routes? Any logic you want to share between them can be in a third function that they both call.

Comment: Daniel, I have already created many routes like that..So thought of reusing the code.,if there are 20 pages in an application, do I need to create 20 route functions for that? Flask should have something for that.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There are a couple of ways that you can handle this with routes.

You can dig into the `request` object to learn which rule triggered the call to the view function.

- `request.url_rule` will give you the rule that was provided as the
  first argument to the `@app.route` decorator, verbatim. This will
  include any variable part of the route specified with `<variable>`.
- Use `request.endpoint` which defaults to the name of the view
  function, however, it can be explicitly set using the `endpoint`
  argument to `@app.route`. I'd prefer this because it can be a short
  string rather than the full rule string, and you can change the rule without having to update the view function.

Here's an example:

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/test/contr/', endpoint='contr', methods=["POST", "GET"])
@app.route('/test/primary/', endpoint='primary', methods=["POST", "GET"])
def test():
    if request.endpoint == 'contr':
        msg = 'View function test() called from "contr" route'
    elif request.endpoint == 'primary':
        msg = 'View function test() called from "primary" route'
    else:
        msg = 'View function test() called unexpectedly'

    return msg

app.run()
```

---

Another method is to pass a `defaults` dictionary to `@app.route`. The dictionary will be passed to the view function as keyword arguments:

```
@app.route('/test/contr/', default={'route': 'contr'}, methods=["POST", "GET"])
@app.route('/test/primary/', default={'route': 'primary'}, methods=["POST", "GET"])

def test(**kwargs):
    return 'View function test() called with route {}'.format(kwargs.get('route'))
```

Comment: Thank you so much dude. You saved my day...This is what I was looking for. Can you please share any doc which has the detail description of the same

Comment: @Priyavv: there is some info here http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#url-route-registrations, and http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#incoming-request-data

Comment: the endpoint can be set but it based on route. if the path is `admin/site`  set `endpoint='site'`, the result will be `admin.site`, not only `site`